# In Android Studio How To Show Buttons With Text in different Locations?

Tags: android

In Android Studio I want to show buttons with characters in 4 corners of the buttons, look like the following :

[image]

So I tried the following :

```
<string name="T_button_2_1">A b c d</string>
<string name="T_button_2_2"><Html><table><Tr><Td>A b</Td><Td> C d</Td></Tr></table></Html></string>
```

But they all show up together like this :

[image]

So what is the proper way to achieve that ?

Comment: If you're just trying to display HTML text in a button then from Java/Kotlin you can do `button.setText(Html.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.T_button_2_2)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this :

```
String text="2 <big>\u24be</big><br><small>\u2665</small> <big>\u2709</big>";
Button button = findViewById(R.id.myButton);
button.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
button.setTextSize(23);
button.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Looks like this :

[image]